# Using the AWS javascript SDK, V3, is there a credentials provider chain equivalent?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk-js

I'm migrating from V2 to V3 of the javascript SDK for AWS, using NodeJS. Our application needs to check for credentials in a couple places. Previously we used the [Credential Provider Chain](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CredentialProviderChain.html) but I cannot find the equivalent in V3. I need to look in the shared INI file (`SharedIniFileCredential`) when my script runs locally but the script also runs in kubernetes so (I think) I also need `roleAssumerWithWebIdentity`. How do I use a credential chain in V3?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The module [@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-js-v3/tree/main/packages/credential-provider-node) provides a default credential provider similar to what you're looking for:

> It will attempt to find credentials from the following sources (listed in order of precedence):
>
> - Environment variables exposed via process.env
> - SSO credentials from token cache
> - Web identity token credentials
> - Shared credentials and config ini files
> - The EC2/ECS Instance Metadata Service

Here's an example from their page:

```
const { getDefaultRoleAssumerWithWebIdentity } = require("@aws-sdk/client-sts");
const { defaultProvider } = require("@aws-sdk/credential-provider-node");
const { S3Client, GetObjectCommand } = require("@aws-sdk/client-s3");

const provider = defaultProvider({
  roleAssumerWithWebIdentity: getDefaultRoleAssumerWithWebIdentity(),
});

const client = new S3Client({ credentialDefaultProvider: provider });
```